# Navigate through UserControl with MVVM LIGHT (WPF)

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, user-controls, mvvm-light

First of all I apologize for my poor english which is not my first language.

I'm new in MVVM so my question is probably a very newbie one ;)

I'm encountering some issue with switching View in a C# Application using WPF and MVVM LIGHT. I've read a lot of articles but i still can't figured out how to do it in a clean way.

So here is my question: What is the best way to achieve the navigation between UserControl contained in a MainWindows, assuming that:

- I've a ViewModel for each UserControl and one for the Main Windows.
- The buttons for switching between usercontrols are contained into UserControl itself
- I've a ViewModelLocator
- I need to sometimes Destroy/re-create a userControl's ViewModel
- I want to respect the MVVM Pattern.
- I want to keep it simple

Comment: Check this out: https://rachel53461.wordpress.com/2011/07/17/navigation-with-mvvm/

Comment: I've already read this article, but it's not talking about MVVM Light, and there is no ViewModelLocator. It's not what i'm looking for. But thanks for trying to help me :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since nobody answers to my question, this is what I finally did. 
It might not be the best way but at least it works well.
I hope it'll helps some newbies like me who are struggling learning this pattern:

**Put a CurrentViewModel Object in the MainViewModel:**

```
public class MainViewModel : ViewModelBase,IMainViewModel
{ 
    /* Other piece of code */

    private ViewModelBase _currentViewModel;

     public ViewModelBase CurrentViewModel
     {
         get
         {
             return _currentViewModel;
         }
         set
         {
             _currentViewModel = value;
             RaisePropertyChanged(() => CurrentViewModel);
         }
     }  
}
```

**Obviously bind this to the Mainview (Just the relevant code):**

```
<UserControl Content="{Binding Path=CurrentViewModel}"/>
```

**Put the DataTemplate in the App.xaml:**

```
  <Application.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <vm:ViewModelLocator x:Key="Locator" d:IsDataSource="True" />
            <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type localViewModel:HomeViewModel }">
                <localView:AccueilView/>
            </DataTemplate>
            <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type localViewModel:ErrorViewModel }">
                <localView:ErrorView/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Application.Resources>
```

**Register the ViewModel with Simple IOC in the ViewModelLocator:**

```
if (ViewModelBase.IsInDesignModeStatic)
{
    SimpleIoc.Default.Register<IHomeViewModel, DesignHomeViewModel>();
}
else
{
    SimpleIoc.Default.Register<IHomeViewModel, HomeViewModel>();
}
```

**Set the getter of all the ViewModel in the ViewModelLocator to Static (just one for the exemple)**

```
public static IHomeViewModel Home
{
    get{return ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<IHomeViewModel>();}
}
```

**Since it's static you can access the ViewModel you want from the MainViewModel:**

```
public class MainViewModel : ViewModelBase,IMainViewModel
{
        public ViewModelBase HomeVM
        {
            get
            {
                return (ViewModelBase)ViewModelLocator.Home;
            }
        }
}
```

**Provide the ability to unregister the ViewModel and recreates it:**

```
public static void CleanUpHome()
{
    SimpleIoc.Default.Unregister<HomeViewModel>();
    SimpleIoc.Default.Register<IHomeViewModel, HomeViewModel>();
}
```

**The "child" View Model communicates with the MainViewModel through messages:**

```
public class ErrorViewModel : ViewModelBase, IErrorViewModel
{     
    /*Other piece of code */

        public void HomeReturn()
        {
            var msg = new ChangeView(ChangeView.EnumView.Home);
            Messenger.Default.Send<ChangeView>(msg);
            ViewModelLocator.CleanUpErrors();
        }
}
```

**The MainViewModel Register to the message and processes it:**

```
public class MainViewModel : ViewModelBase,IMainViewModel
{
    public MainViewModel()
    {
        Messenger.Default.Register<ChangeView>(this, (action) => ReceiveMessage(action));
        CurrentViewModel = HomeVM;
    }

    private void ReceiveMessage(ChangeView viewName)
    {
        switch (viewName.switchView)
        {
            case ChangeView.EnumView.Home:
                CurrentViewModel = HomeVM;
                break;
            case ChangeView.EnumView.Error:
                CurrentViewModel = ErrorVM;
                break;
            }
        Messenger.Default.Unregister<ChangeView>(this, (action) => ReceiveMessage(action));
    }
```

That's all.